# The outer measure is additive for sets at positive distance

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Please help me prove this in detail because I have a really hard time in Analysis. Thank you in advance. This is the problem: Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded sets for which there is an $\alpha > 0$ such that $|a-b| \geq \alpha$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$. Prove $m^*(A \cup B)= m^*(A) +m^*(B)$.

Comment: I assume that your condition was intended to read $|a-b|≥\alpha$?

Comment: Yes..|a-b|>=α..

Comment: You should probably clarify what you mean by $m^*$ or $m*$ or whatever you meant.

Comment: @skyking. m* means outer measures.. Thank you for editing my question..

Comment: @DylanSp.. Thank you so much..

Comment: @skyking. What is the form or how to write our $A$ and $B$? Please help..

Comment: @lulu. What is the form or how to write our $A$ and $B$? Please help

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The argument given below by @skyking looks solid.  To emphasize, axiomatic subadditivity tells us that the outer measure of the union can not exceed the sum of the outer measures...your condition lets us establish the opposite inequality.   If you want to read more about it, these online notes look ok (your question is Lemma $26$):  http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/section1.4.pdf

Comment: @lulu.. Thank you so much for the link.It helps a lot.. I reported it with flying colors..God Bless.

Comment: no effort spent! So I down voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_r = \{x: |x-a|\le r, \forall a\in A\}$. It should be obvious that $A_r$ is closed and bounded and therefore compact. Now if we cover $A_{\alpha/2}$, and $B_{\alpha/2}$ with open discs of radius $alpha/4$ we have that the covers would not intersect and since they are compact we have a finite cover.

Recall the definition of outer measure:

$$m^*(E) = \inf_{\mathscr I\textrm{ covers }E} \sum_\mathscr I m(I)$$

where $\mathscr I$ are (finite or countably finite, depending on your definition) families of intervals.

Therefore if we have an interval-cover of $A\cup B$ we can use the above construct to decompose it into covers of $A$ and $B$. In addition we have that the new cover will have the same total measure. On the other hand if we have a cover of $A$ and $B$ we can combine them to cover $A\cup B$ with the same measure (note that if intervals in an interval-cover are overlapping we will still add the measures of the intervals).

Now if we put this together, the first construct gives us that $m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ is no larger than any of the sums we take infimum over in $m^*(A\cup B)$ which means that $m^*(A)+m^*(B) \le m^*(A\cup B)$. On the other way for each pair of sums we take infimum over in $m^*(A)$ and $m^*(B)$ we have that their sum is equal to one of the sums we take infimum over in $m^*(A\cup B)$ so we have that their sum is no smaller than $m^*(A\cup B)$, therefore we can conclude that $m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.

Comment: I got it..It is my report and I pass it with flying colors.. I am using the measurable definition.. Thank you so much for the idea..God Bless..