# A non-measurable set which satisfies a given condtion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question: Find a non-measuarble set $E$ inside $I=[0,1]$ which satisfies the relation below.

$$ \frac {1}{2}\lt m^*(I-E)\lt m^*(E)\lt 1$$

where $m^*$ stands for outer-measure.

My attempt: First, divide $I=[0,1]$ into two parts, $I_1=[0,\frac {1}{2}]$ and $I_2=[\frac {1}{2},1]$. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be, respectively, two arbitrary Vitali sets inside $I_1$ and $I_2$. Now, put $E_1=V_1 \cup {V_2}^c$ where ${V_2}^c$ is the complement of $V_2$ when $I_2$ is considered to be the whole set.

Also the same procedure, $E_2=V_2 \cup {V_1}^c$ where ${V_1}^c$ is the complement of $V_1$ when $I_2$ is considered to be the whole set.

In the end, I claim that either $E_1$ or $E_2$ is the desired set.

**Is my example working?**

---

I know that the outer measure of the compliment of a Vitali set inside $[0,a]$ is equal to $a$. That's why I am following such a path to build an example. I may be missing something very obvious and simple so any help or solution would be highly appreciated.

---

According to the the link below, I think my example works if we make $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that their distances, respectively, from $I_2$ and $I_1$ are larger than zero. (notice that the outer measure of a Vitali set is always larger than zero.)

[The outer measure is additive for sets at positive distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661378/the-outer-measure-is-additive-for-sets-at-positive-distance)

Comment: interesting exercise, where you found it? (Sorry, I dont know if your attempt will work)

Comment: @Masacroso   I just came across this question accidentally :)) BTW, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Vitali set, I think it might be easier to use a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set). Let $B$ be a Bernstein subset of $[0,\frac12]$; then $B\subset[0,\frac12]$ and $m^*([0,\frac12]\cap B)=\frac12$ and $m^*([0,\frac12]\setminus B)=\frac12$. Now let $E=B\cup[\frac12,\frac56]\subset[0,1]$; then $m^*(E)=\frac56$ and $m^*([0,1]\setminus E)=\frac23$.

**P.S.** By a "Bernstein subset" of an interval $I$, I mean a subset $B\subset I$ such that both $B$ and $I\setminus B$ have nonempty intersection with every uncountable closed subset of $I$. If $I=\mathbb R$ these are the usual Bernstein sets.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of Bernstein sets at all. As far as I know, a Bernstein set is a subset of the real line. I can't make any sense of $\frac{1}{1}$ but it seems, if we let $B$ be a Bernstein set, then $(B \cap [0, \frac{1}{2})]) \cup [ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{6}]$ works. Anyway, it was very helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: BTW, I know it might be a mental obsession but I prefer to pick $[\frac{3}{5}, \frac{5}{6}]$ instead of $[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{6}]$ to make sure that I can easily add two outer-measures. (Also, about my attempt above)

Comment: Sorry, $\frac11$ was a typo for $\frac12$.

Comment: The advantage of a Bernstein set over a Vitali set is that its complement is a Bernstein set too . Also, both have zero inner measure. Am I right?

Comment: How are you sure that there is at least one Bernstein set of a given interval $I$. Is that enough to consider $B\cap I$ where $B$ is a Bernstein set in the real line.?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe Vitali sets require a weaker form of the axiom of choice, but I don't know about that.

Comment: Yes, if $B$ is a classical Bernstein set, then $B\cap I$ will be what I call "a Bernstein subset of $I$". (I don't know if anybody else uses that terminology, it seemed natural to me.) Alternatively, take an order-preserving bijection between the real line and the interval $(a,b)$, and the image of a Bernstein subset of $\mathbb R$ will be a Bernstein subset of $(a,b)$. As a third alternative, construct a Bernstein subset of $I$ directly by the same method used for $\mathbb R$, i.e., start by well-ordering the collection of all uncountable closed subsets of $I$ . . ..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help and time.